# Is there a tool or a way to track dependency version across multiple Gradle projects?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, shared-libraries

I would like to scan multiple Gradle projects. Is there a tool or a way to track dependency versions across multiple Gradle projects?
That would make life easier to maintain versions of hundreds of dependencies across 20 or 30 projects.